# redirect the user to the same page he came from after successful login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

---

user has been browsing items, in order to see more details needs to login. after login he should be redirected to the page of the item he has been browsing. My problem is instead of doing that it redirects to home page.This is what i have

### itemprofile.php

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="position" value="';
if(isset($_GET['position'])) {
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['position']);
}
echo '" />';`
```

### loginProcess.php

`$direct = NULL;
if($_POST['position'] != '') {
    $direct = $_POST['position'];
}`

```
if(isset($_POST['loginSubmit'])){

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    //get user data from user class
    $conditions['where'] = array(
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'password' => md5($_POST['password']),
        'status' => '1'
    );
    $conditions['return_type'] = 'single';
    $userData = $user->getRows($conditions);
    if($userData){
         $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;
        if($direct) {
            header("Location:". $direct);
        }else{header("Location:" . $url);}

        exit();
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message']='<div style="color: darkred">not valid</div>';
        header("Location:login.php");
        exit();}
         }
```

### login.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    echo $_SESSION['message'];
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}

<form action="loginProcess.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" 
     required="">
        <div class="send-button">
            <input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" value="LOGIN">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: ok. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

You could use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and send this within a input text wich is hidden, but keep in mind this can be changed